# Uploading a File Using 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to upload a file using C#, and the 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' method. All the examples I've seen read the file data into a byte array first, but that won't work for me, because the files I'm sending are over 500MB. So I'm looking for a way to stream the file straight from the disk.

A bonus to this question would be reading the file from a specified byte position, eg instead of starting from the first byte to the last, I could start from the 500th byte to the last.

Answer (score 2):

You should write you data by chunks, so main part of upload should look like

```
var buffer = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = fileData.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
     requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

All upload code.

```
public static class Upload
{
    private const string FileFieldNameDefault = "fileContent";

    public static WebResponse PostFile
        (Uri requestUri, NameValueCollection postData, Stream fileData, string fileName,
         string fileContentType, string fileFieldName, CookieContainer cookies,
         NameValueCollection headers)
    {
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false; 

        if (requestUri.Scheme == "https") 
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, err) => true;
        }

        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);

        webRequest.Method = "POST";

        string boundary = "----------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        webRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;

        string ctype;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileContentType))
            fileContentType = TryGetContentType(fileName, out ctype)
                                ? ctype
                                : "application/octet-stream";

        fileFieldName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileFieldName) ? FileFieldNameDefault : fileFieldName;

        if (headers != null)
            foreach (string key in headers.AllKeys)
            {
                var values = headers.GetValues(key);
                if (values != null)
                    foreach (var value in values)
                        webRequest.Headers.Add(key, value);
            }

        if (cookies != null)
            webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;

        var sbHeader = new StringBuilder();

        if (fileData != null)
        {
            var fileNameValue = string.Empty;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) == false)
                fileNameValue = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "filename=\"{0}\"", Path.GetFileName(fileName));

            sbHeader
                .AppendFormat("--{0}", boundary)
                .AppendLine()
                .AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; {1}", fileFieldName, fileNameValue)
                .AppendLine()
                .AppendFormat("Content-Type: {0}", fileContentType)
                .AppendLine()
                .AppendLine();
        }

        var sbFooter = new StringBuilder();
        sbFooter.AppendLine();

        if (postData != null)
            foreach (var key in postData.AllKeys)
            {
                var values = postData.GetValues(key);
                if (values != null)
                    foreach (var value in values)
                        sbFooter
                            .AppendFormat("--{0}", boundary)
                            .AppendLine()
                            .AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"", key)
                            .AppendLine()
                            .AppendLine()
                            .Append(value)
                            .AppendLine();
            }

        sbFooter.AppendFormat("--{0}--\r\n", boundary);

        byte[] header = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sbHeader.ToString());
        byte[] footer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sbFooter.ToString());
        long contentLength = header.Length + (fileData != null ? fileData.Length : 0) + footer.Length;

        webRequest.ContentLength = contentLength;

        using (var requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(header, 0, header.Length);

            if (fileData != null)
            {
                var buffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = fileData.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                    requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            requestStream.Write(footer, 0, footer.Length);

            return webRequest.GetResponse();
        }
    }

    public static WebResponse PostFile
        (Uri requestUri, NameValueCollection postData, string fileName,
         string fileContentType, string fileFieldName, CookieContainer cookies,
         NameValueCollection headers)
    {
        using (var fileData = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            return PostFile(requestUri, postData, fileData,
                            fileName, fileContentType, fileFieldName, cookies,
                            headers);
    }

    private static bool TryGetContentType(string fileName, out string contentType)
    {
        try
        {
            RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"MIME\Database\Content Type");

            if (key != null)
            {
                foreach (string keyName in from keyName in key.GetSubKeyNames()
                                           let subKey = key.OpenSubKey(keyName)
                                           where subKey != null
                                           let subKeyValue = (string)subKey.GetValue("Extension")
                                           where string.IsNullOrEmpty(subKeyValue) == false
                                           where string.Compare(Path.GetExtension(fileName), subKeyValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0
                                           select keyName)
                {
                    contentType = keyName;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // fail silently
            // TODO: rethrow registry access denied errors
        }
        contentType = string.Empty;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes. Writing in chunks. Not sure why I didn't think of that. I'll let is slide that your example is using 'multipart/form-data' when I asked for 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. :)

Comment: It just my working code, sorry for that, by I havn't so much time to change and test it with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: any sample code for get the file that you upload ? source code sample of requestUri's Page_Load  ?